# Using Variables in layouts using Zend Framework

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, zend-layout

I am trying to learn how to use the Zend Framework and ive ran into trouble. Im trying to place the current users name in the header of the application (displayed on every page), specifically /layouts/scripts/default.phtml.

The MVC architecture is very new to me and confusing me greatly. I do not want to have to place the logic to display this username in the controller every time (this is probably the wrong way to do it anyway), so where would I place the code to assign this variable if not in each controller?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the kind of thing that action helpers were designed for. A full tutorial on them is a bit beyond the scope of SO, but there are several good tutorials available.

Start with the [Zend Framework Documentation](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html) and then take a look at [Mathew Weier O'Phinney's tutorial](http://mwop.net/blog/246-Using-Action-Helpers-To-Implement-Re-Usable-Widgets) and also this one by [Rob Allen](http://akrabat.com/zend-framework/using-action-helpers-in-zend-framework/).

The issue with using a base controller for this kind of thing is that the resources are loaded regardless of wether your controller needs them or not, whereas action helpers are loaded only if needed.

I almost forgot the excellent [ZendCasts have a video on action helpers](http://www.zendcasts.com/introducing-action-helpers/2010/10/).

Comment: Perfect answer. We always think of quick examples to solve specific problems, but we don't always try to understand the big picture. The action helpers tip is a great one!

Comment: *"The issue with using a base controller for this kind of thing is that the resources are loaded regardless of wether your controller needs them or not, whereas action helpers are loaded only if needed."*. Well that's not entirely true. With a proper architecture, you don't have to. The problem with action helpers is that you need to call them if you need them. If you need them everywhere, you have to call them everywhere, and still need a base controller if you don't want to.

Comment: @netcoder I try to avoid using base controllers at all costs. I found they were getting out of hand as I pushed more functionality into them. I can only speak from my own experience, but I am finding action helpers much more manageable than base controllers. I am not saying that base controllers are bad, just that I don't like them :)

Comment: @vascowhite: I'm not saying action helpers are bad either. But base controllers are somewhat inevitable in most projects, unless you want to copy-paste code all over the place.

Comment: @netcoder I don't have any repeated code using action helpers, just lines like `$this->view->user = $this->user()` in a controller that needs a user object. Works for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You want a base controller and to assign that in the `preDispatch` method:

```
class MyApp_Controller_Action extends Zend_Controller_Action {
    public function preDispatch() {
        parent::preDispatch();
        Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance()->assign('username', getCurrentUserName());
    }
}
```

Then extend your own controllers with that new class:

```
class MyApp_Module_ActionController extends MyApp_Controller_Action {

}
```

Then in your layout view:

```
echo $this->layout()->username;
```

Answer (score 0):

First, read the manual, and than try to accomplish something like this:

```
class BaseController extends Zend_Controller_Action {

    public function preDispatch() {
        // your logic to show the user name goes here
    }

}

class SomePageController extends BaseController {}

class SomeOtherPageController extends BaseController {}
```

This will most likely solve your problem.